# In Perl how to find the date of the previous Monday for a given date?

Tags: perl, date

I am looking for a Perl script which can give me the last Monday for any specified date.

e.g. For date 2011-06-11, the script should return 2011-06-06

Comment: have you had a go at this already? what did you try?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm assuming that if the given date is a Monday, you want the same date (and not the previous Monday).  Here's one way to do it with [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime):

```
use DateTime;

my $date = DateTime->new(year => 2011, month => 6, day => 11);
my $desired_dow = 1;            # Monday
$date->subtract(days => ($date->day_of_week - $desired_dow) % 7);
print "$date\n";
```

(Actually, for the special case of Monday, the `% 7` isn't necessary, because `$date->day_of_week - 1` will always be 0–6, and that mod 7 is a no-op.  But with the `% 7`, it works for *any* desired day-of-week, not just Monday.)

If you did want the previous Monday, you can change the subtraction:

```
$date->subtract(days => ($date->day_of_week - $desired_dow) % 7 || 7);
```

If you need to parse a date entered on the command line, you might want to look at [DateTime::Format::Natural](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime::Format::Natural).

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this and a lot of date/time modules on CPAN, but DateTime is by far the best module for doing anything with dates and times.

Answer (score 12):

You could also use Time::ParseDate, which understand "last Monday".

A one-liner to maintain Perl's reputation:

```
perl -MTime::ParseDate -M'POSIX qw(strftime)' -l -e'foreach (@ARGV) { my $now= parsedate( $_); my $e= parsedate( "last Monday", NOW => $now) ; print "$_ : ", strftime "%F", localtime( $e)}' 2011-06-11 2011-06-12 2011-06-13 2011-06-14
```

And a sane script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::ParseDate;    # to parse dates
use POSIX qw(strftime); # to format dates

foreach my $date (@ARGV) 
  { my $date_epoch= parsedate( $date) || die"'cannot parse date '$date'\n";
    my $monday= parsedate( "last Monday", NOW => $date_epoch);                  # last Monday before NOW
    print "Monday before $date: ", strftime( "%F", localtime( $monday)), "\n";  # %F is YYYY-MM-DD
  }
```

A couple of notes: if the date is a Monday, then you get the **previous** Monday, which may or may not be what you want, to change that just set NOW to the next day (add 60*60*24, a day, to $date_epoch). Then Time::ParseDate is pretty liberal, it will happily parse 2011-23-38 for example (as 2012-12-09).

Comment: While `DateTime` is a canonical way to work with dates and times in Perl, `Time::ParseDate` has always been my favorite for this sort of things.

Comment: I actually rarely have to work with dates, which maybe why I find parsedate( "last Monday", NOW => $date_epoch); cute and, more important, easy to remember.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty simple stuff using the standard Perl library.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Local;
use POSIX 'strftime';

my $date = shift || die "No date given\n";

my @date = split /-/, $date;
$date[0] -= 1900;
$date[1]--;

die "Invalid date: $date\n" unless @date == 3;

my $now = timelocal(0, 0, 12, reverse @date);

while (strftime('%u', localtime $now) != 1) {
  $now -= 24 * 60 * 60;
}
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to look up the various modules and functions used.

It's probably even simpler if you use DateTime.

Answer (score 3):

In the spirit of Perl, There Is More Than One Way To Do It.

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Date::Calc qw/Day_of_Week/;
my $date = '2011/6/11';
my @fields = split /\//, $date;
my @new_date = Add_Delta_Days( @fields , 1 - Day_of_Week( @fields ) );
say join "/", @new_date;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Date::Manip](http://p3rl.org/Date%3a%3aManip), which has a `Date_GetPrev` function and understands "Monday"

```
$ perl -MDate::Manip -le 'print UnixDate(Date_GetPrev(shift, "Monday", 0), "%Y-%m-%d")' 2011-06-11
2011-06-06
```

Answer (score 1):

[Zeller's congruence](http://www.cpan.org/scripts/date_and_time/zeller.date.pl) will give you the day of the week. From there it should be pretty easy.

Comment: That's a newspost of a newspost. Alternative link to original posting, better readable: [`<Message-ID: 1990Oct2.172114.6421@amd.com>`](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.perl/msg/dbd4d19f71ec6b9a)

Comment: @daxim, not to mention totally unnecessary in Perl 5. `( localtime )[6]` is day-of-week.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of this, `$tstamp` would have the timestamp you want:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw<mktime>;

my $time = '2011-06-11';

my ( $year, $month, $day ) = split /-0?/, $time;
my $tstamp = mktime( 0, 0, 0, $day, $month - 1, $year - 1900 );
my $dow  = ( localtime $tstamp )[6];
$tstamp -= (( $dow > 1 ? 0 : 7 ) + $dow - 1 ) * 24 * 60 * 60;
```

This assumes that by "last Monday" you mean the last occurring Monday *prior* to the given day." So if the day of the week is Monday (1), then it subtracts and additional 7.

Comment: You're off by one on you dow test, 2011-06-07 (Tuesday) will return the timestamp for 2011-05-30.

Comment: @Ven'Tatsu Ah, I outsmarted myself. I tested, posted, and then read the comparative wrong and hastily changed it to a 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a slave like me and have to use a corporate Perl without libraries and you are not allowed to install them either, old fashioned way:

```
my $datestring = "";
my $secondsEpoc = time(); #gives the seconds from system epoch
my $secondsWantedDate;
my $seconds2substract;

$datestring = localtime($secondsEpoc);
print "Today's date and time ".$datestring."\n";
my ($second,$minute,$hour,$d,$M,$y,$wd,$yd) = (localtime)[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
#print "hour: ".$hour;
#print "minute: ".$minute;
#print "second: ".$second;
#print "week day: ".$wd; #week day is 1=Monday .. 7=Sunday

$seconds2substract = 24 * 60 * 60;  # seconds in 24 hours
$secondsWantedDate=$secondsEpoc-$seconds2substract;
$datestring = localtime($secondsWantedDate);
print "Yesterday at the same time ".$datestring."\n";


my $days2Substract = $wd-1;
$seconds2substract = ($days2Substract * 24 * 60 * 60);
$secondsWantedDate=$secondsEpoc-$seconds2substract;
$datestring = localtime($secondsWantedDate);
print "Past Monday same time ".$datestring."\n";

$seconds2substract = ($days2Substract * 24 * 60 * 60) + ($hour *60 *60) + ($minute * 60) + $second;
$secondsWantedDate = $secondsEpoc-$seconds2substract;
$datestring = localtime($secondsWantedDate);
print "Past Monday at 00:00:00  ".$datestring."\n";
```

Hope it helps somebody!

Comment: You are right, but it serves for many purposes where the leap second is not important: believe me, not been allowed to add libraries is hell, it can make your code grow in lines ridiculously, and all you mind is to find a fast solution that is good enough for the required task  :)

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of ways to do it in Perl. Here is how it can be done with Perl library [Moment](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moment).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Moment;

sub get_monday_date {
    my ($date) = @_;

    my $moment = Moment->new( dt => "$date 00:00:00" );

    my $weekday_number = $moment->get_weekday_number( first_day => 'monday' );

    my $monday = $moment->minus( day => ($weekday_number - 1) );

    return $monday->get_d();
}

say get_monday_date('2011-06-11'); # 2011-06-06
```