# In Perl, how can I find last Thursday's date?

Tags: perl, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Perl, how can find the date of the previous Monday for a given date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262151/in-perl-how-can-find-the-date-of-the-previous-monday-for-a-given-date)

In the perl, how to write a function to get last Thursday's date? Today (11/21), I want to get 11/17. How can I figure out if a given date is a Sunday or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get previous Monday for a given date in Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262151/get-previous-monday-for-a-given-date-in-perl) ([my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262151/get-previous-monday-for-a-given-date-in-perl/6262634#6262634) there is generalized to any day-of-week).

Comment: Highly related: [Timestamp of last monday](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=938835)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like a work for [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime) (which is the module usually recommended to manipulate dates in Perl). This small example should answer both your questions:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime;

my $d = DateTime->now;

while ( $d->day_of_week != 4 ) {
    $d->subtract( days => 1 );
}

print $d->ymd;
```

Comment: do we have function to convert to  this format: '20111117' ?

Comment: yes. DateTime implements a strftime() method. The documentation gives you details about the format directives: https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime#strftime-Patterns

Comment: This can give the wrong result. See [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213958/in-perl-how-can-i-find-last-thursdays-date/8216977#8216977) for details.

Answer (score 6):

Other posts use [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) too, but they have issues this post addresses.

```
use DateTime qw( );
my $dt = DateTime->today( time_zone => 'local' );
$dt->subtract( days => ($dt->day_of_week - 4) % 7 );
say $dt->ymd('');  # 20111117
```

Issues addressed:

- Uses the local date instead of the date in or near England.
- Uses `today` instead of `now` since you're only dealing with dates.
- Avoids needless loops.

Note:

- Returns the current date is today is a Thursday. You accepted an answer that did the same, so I presume that's what you want.

---

Update: The above can fail on certain days for certain time zones. (Not all days have a midnight!) Solution:

```
use DateTime qw( );
my $dt = DateTime->now( time_zone => 'local' );
$dt->set_time_zone('floating');
$dt->truncate( to => 'days' );
$dt->subtract( days => ($dt->day_of_week - 4) % 7 );
say $dt->ymd('');  # 20111117
```

Comment: Running your code on Monday 2011-11-21, I get 20111118, not 20111117. I had better luck with '$dt->subtract( days => ($dt->day_of_week + 7 - 4) % 7 );'

Comment: @Chris Charley, I had the operands reversed. Fixed. Your `+ 7` is useless. `($x + 7) % 7` is the same as `$x % 7`.

Comment: I have read about modulo a negative number but I didn't really understand them. From this problem I think I see how they work. If   -13 % 7, then the result of division would be -2 with a remainder of +1, (equal -13).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use what larsen wrote, although reading the [localtime reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) won't hurt you. You could do something like this to check if its Sunday:

```
($second, $minute, $hour, $dayOfMonth, $month, $yearOffset, 
                         $dayOfWeek, $dayOfYear, $daylightSavings) = localtime();
if ($dayOfWeek == 0) print("Don't go to work!");
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you wanted to test was the day-of-the-week an array slice of the localtime() works nicely:

```
print q(Today is Sunday) if ((localtime)[6]==0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Date::Calc](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Date%3a%3aCalc#9):

> How do I calculate the last and the next Saturday for any given date?

```
  use Date::Calc qw( Today Day_of_Week Add_Delta_Days
                     Day_of_Week_to_Text Date_to_Text );

  $searching_dow = 6; # 6 = Saturday

  @today = Today();

  $current_dow = Day_of_Week(@today);

  if ($searching_dow == $current_dow)
  {
      @prev = Add_Delta_Days(@today,-7);
      @next = Add_Delta_Days(@today,+7);
  }
  else
  {
      if ($searching_dow > $current_dow)
      {
          @next = Add_Delta_Days(@today,
                    $searching_dow - $current_dow);
          @prev = Add_Delta_Days(@next,-7);
      }
      else
      {
          @prev = Add_Delta_Days(@today,
                    $searching_dow - $current_dow);
          @next = Add_Delta_Days(@prev,+7);
      }
  }

  $dow = Day_of_Week_to_Text($searching_dow);

  print "Today is:      ", ' ' x length($dow),
                               Date_to_Text(@today), "\n";
  print "Last $dow was:     ", Date_to_Text(@prev),  "\n";
  print "Next $dow will be: ", Date_to_Text(@next),  "\n";
```

Comment: Whose date does `Today` return? Local or UTC?

Comment: As the documentation (linked above) states, `Today()` is localtime. `Today('utc')` (or invoked with any true value), will give you UTC.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Date::Calc qw(:all);

($week, $year) = Week_of_Year(Today());# Week_of_Year(2011,11,21);
print Date_to_Text(Add_Delta_Days(Monday_of_Week($week - 1,$year),3));#THU - MON = 3
#output:Thu 17-Nov-2011

#isSunday?
Day_of_Week(2011,11,20) == 7 # 7 is Sunday enum code(from 1 : Monday)
```

Answer (score 0):

Date::Simple has a pretty clean interface.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Date::Simple qw/ today /;

my $d = today;

# If today is already Thurs, subtract 1 before searching for prior Thursday.
# If today is Thurs and you want to capture that (and not Thur a week ago),
# don't subtract the 1 from $d.
$d--; 

$d-- while $d->day_of_week != 4;    
print $d->strftime("%Y%m%d");
```

Comment: Whose date does `today` return? Local or UTC?

Comment: @ikegami Not sure. Looking thru the source, there is some function like _gmtime(), but afraid I can't read the code well enough to see if local time is used or UTC. Printing the date after 00:00 UTC still gave me today's date ((New_York time zone, EST).

Comment: It uses `my ( $y, $m, $d ) = (localtime)[ 5, 4, 3 ]; $y += 1900; $m += 1; return $_[0]->_ymd( $y, $m, $d );`, so local date.

Answer (score 0):

With just `localtime` and the [`POSIX`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POSIX) base module, you can do this:

```
my @ltime = localtime();
my $t 
    = POSIX::mktime(( 0 ) x 3
    , $ltime[3] - ( 7 - 4 + $ltime[6] )
    , @ltime[4,5] 
    );
```

This will always give you the last Thursday before the last Sunday. So if the day is Saturday, it will give you the previous week's Thursday, but if it's Sunday, it will give you the last past Thursday.

If you prefer the last past Thursday computation, you might do this:

```
my $t 
    = POSIX::mktime(( 0 ) x 3
    , $ltime[3] - $ltime[6] + ( $ltime[6] > 4 ?  4 : -3 )
    , @ltime[4,5] 
    );
```

Comment: Negative values aren't valid for `mktime`, so it can't possibly "always give you the last Thursday before the last Sunday". (tm_mday: The day of the month, in the range 1 to 31.)

Comment: @ikegami negative values have worked in `mktime` every time I've tried them.

Comment: Negative values most certainly are valid for `mktime`; `mktime` will happily convert any out-of-range values in any fields by borrow/carry on higher fields. It is entirely this ability of it that makes it so simple and useful in this sort of calculation