# Perl DateTime Module Calculating First, Second, Third , Fouth, Last Sunday,Monday,... Saturday of every month

Tags: perl, date, datetime

I was working with Perl **[DateTime Module](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.03/lib/DateTime.pm)**, I was wondering how will I calculate  `First`, `Second`, `Third`, `Fourth` and `Last` `Sunday's`, `Monday's`,... `Saturday's` of specified month.

**My Approach**:

Run a Loop from i= 1...DateTime->last_day_of_month( ... ) .

Assign date i to date($dt) and fetch the day of week using $dt->day_of_week().

Use counter to keep track of  first, second, third, fourth, last.

Break the loop if  day of week matches the desired day and counter matches the desired interval.

*Can you suggest a better(or short) approach than above?
Any help is appreciated.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a straightforward modification of [my answer for finding the previous Monday (or any specified day of the week)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6262634/8355).  The only difficulty is figuring out what date you start with.

```
use DateTime;

# Here $nth is 1, 2, 3... for first, second, third, etc.
# Or -1, -2, -3... for last, next-to-last, etc.
# $dow is 1-7 for Monday-Sunday
# $month is 1-12
sub nth_day_of_month {
  my ($nth, $dow, $year, $month) = @_;

  my $date = ($nth > 0
              # For 1st etc. we want the last day of that week
              # (i.e. 7, 14, 21, 28 ...).  We have to use add because
              # the last week may extend into next month.
              ? DateTime->new(year => $year, month => $month, day => 1)
                        ->add( days => $nth * 7 - 1)
              # For last etc. we want the last day of the month
              # (minus a week if next-to-last, etc)
              : DateTime->last_day_of_month(year => $year, month => $month)
                        ->add( weeks => $nth + 1)); # $nth is negative

  # Back up to the first $dow on or before $date
  $date->subtract(days => ($date->day_of_week - $dow) % 7);

  # If we're not in the right month, then that month doesn't have the
  # specified date (e.g. there's no 5th Tuesday in Sept. 2013).
  return (($date->month == $month) ? $date : undef);
}
```

**Update:** Here's a slightly more efficient version.  It's using the same algorithm, but it's combining the calls to `add` and `subtract`, so it only has to do date math once.

```
sub nth_day_of_month {
  my ($nth, $dow, $year, $month) = @_;

  my ($date, $delta);
  if ($nth > 0) {
    # For 1st etc. we want the last day of that week (i.e. 7, 14, 21, 28, "35")
    $date  = DateTime->new(year => $year, month => $month, day => 1);
    $delta = $nth * 7 - 1;
  } else {
    # For last etc. we want the last day of the month
    # (minus a week if next-to-last, etc)
    $date  = DateTime->last_day_of_month(year => $year, month => $month);
    $delta = 7 * ($nth + 1); # $nth is negative
  }

  # Back up to the first $dow on or before $date + $delta
  $date->add(days => $delta - ($date->day_of_week + $delta - $dow) % 7);

  # If we're not in the right month, then that month doesn't have the
  # specified date (e.g. there's no 5th Tuesday in Sept. 2013).
  return (($date->month == $month) ? $date : undef);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. +1 for the explanation in form of comment.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to tap into the module [Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip-6.41/lib/Date/Manip.pod):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Date::Manip::Base;

my $dmb = new Date::Manip::Base;

# First Tuesday in October 2013
my $year  = 2013;
my $Nth   = 1;      # 1 = first
my $dow   = 2;      # 2 = Tuesday (day of week)
my $month = 10;     # October

# $ymd is an array reference
my $ymd = $dmb->nth_day_of_week( $year, $Nth, $dow, $month );

print join '-', @$ymd; # prints 2013-10-1
```

To parse a date string, you can do the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Date::Manip::Date;

my $date = new Date::Manip::Date;

$date->parse('First Tuesday in October 2013');

print $date->printf('%Y-%m-%d'); # prints 2013-10-01
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's the 21st century. Date::Manip is **never** the right answer :-)

Comment: @DaveCross - It's Friday.  Beware of universal quantifications in this context, as they're inherently fragile. ;-)