# Automatically put working week

Tags: perl

Right now i am working on a weekly basis gathering the data and put the week and month manually. For example: The working week for today this week is June 23 thru June 29. and the month is June 2014.

I want to gather the YTD data and based on the date put the Week and Month automatically

*For example:*

#### Referral Request Date    Week    Month

1/3/2014 0:00   December 30 thru January 05, 2014   January 2014
1/3/2014 11:10  December 30 thru January 05, 2014   January 2014
12/31/2013 0:00 December 30 thru January 05, 2014   December 2013
6/18/2014 0:00  June 16 thru June 22, 2014  June 2014
6/20/2014 9:51  June 16 thru June 22, 2014  June 2014
4/28/2014 16:34 April 28 thru May 04, 2014  April 2014
5/1/2014 15:22  April 28 thru May 04, 2014  May 2014

The working week will begin each monday and finished on Sunday.

It can be do automatically?? The file have thousand of lines...

Comment: This may be of use: [in perl how can find the date of the previous monday for a given date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262151/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my @datetimes = (
    '1/3/2014 0:00',
    '1/3/2014 11:10',
    '12/31/2013 0:00',
    '6/18/2014 0:00',
    '6/20/2014 9:51',
    '4/28/2014 16:34',
    '5/1/2014 15:22',
);


for my $datetime_str (@datetimes) {

    my $strp = 'DateTime::Format::Strptime'->new( pattern => '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M' );
    my $dt = $strp->parse_datetime($datetime_str);

    my $month_year_strp = 'DateTime::Format::Strptime'->new( pattern => '%B %Y' );
    my $month_year = $month_year_strp->format_datetime($dt);

    my $desired_dow = 1; # Monday
    $dt->subtract(days => ($dt->day_of_week - $desired_dow) % 7);
    my $month_day_strp = 'DateTime::Format::Strptime'->new( pattern => '%B %d' );
    my $monday = $month_day_strp->format_datetime($dt);

    $dt->add(days => 6);
    my $sunday = $month_day_strp->format_datetime($dt);

    say "$datetime_str, $monday thru $sunday, $month_year";
}
```

Next time help someone else (in case this is what you're after -- I am not sure if I got your question). :-) I used the link posted by @scragar in comments.